# MySQL alternative way to `CASE` Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

May I know, is there any alternative way or short way to write this `case` statement shown in the below:

```
case 
  when p.our_price IS NULL OR p.our_price = 0 
   then p.sales_price 
  else p.our_price 
end as sales_price
```

I tried using mysql built in funciton `ifnull` as below:

`ifnull(p.our_price,p.sales_price)`

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If present, is `our_price` always less than (or greater than) `sales_price`?

Comment: `IF(COALESCE(p.our_price, 0) = 0, p.sales_price, p.our_price)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stick with a `CASE` expression but use `COALESCE` to make it more succinct:

```sql
CASE COALESCE(p.our_price, 0)
     WHEN 0 THEN p.sales_price ELSE p.our_price END AS sales_price
```

Or, using the `IF()` function:

```sql
IF(COALESCE(p.our_price, 0) = 0, p.sales_price, p.our_price)
```

As a long time MySQL user, I often find myself using `CASE` more than `IF()` as the former allows omitting the `ELSE` condition entirely.  `IF()` on the other hand always requires an explicit else value.

Answer (score 3):

```
IF(p.our_price IS NULL OR p.our_price = 0, p.sales_price, p.our_price)
```

the 1st argument is the condition, 2nd and 3rd are the choices in case the condition is true or false.